# Can't get Disqus commenting to work on Github Page Blog

Tags: github, comments, blogs, disqus

I'm trying to add comments to my github page blog, and nothing happens when I add the code. No matter where I paste it. I've tried three different approaches so far:

1. Per the [JB installation documentation](http://jekyllbootstrap.com/usage/blog-configuration.html), I specified "disqus" as the provider and added my disqus short_name in my _config.yml file. That actually should have done it because the Jekyll Bootstrap ships with the JS widget that disqus provides when you sign up for an account. It's in the includes folder.
2. Since that didn't work, I found the widget and added an include statement to my post.html template referencing it. This also didn't work.
3. Since none of that worked (and I still insist I shouldn't have to paste the JS since it's already included with JB, but I was desperate at this point), I pasted the JS that disqus provided when I signed up for my account in the post.html in layouts and includes - I did this one at a time, testing each time I pasted.

Each time I did this, my page didn't change at all. It was like I did nothing.

I've googled this to death, and looked at the source of [another github page that's successfully using disqus](https://github.com/staceybaker1974/erjjones.github.com) - the only thing that looked different is that he has his JS pasted into a layout.html page - I don't have one of those. I only have post & page. And I'm definitely trying to add comments to my posts, not my pages.

Comment: Can you help me on how to create a page on github?

Comment: Sure, I've been doing it all day. :) What's your question, specifically?

Comment: I have a github account and I want to publish a page of mine , When I go about the docs it didn't wrk for me. Tell me in very basic steps how to make a github page.

Comment: Posting just a page (as opposed to a blog) is super easy, so don't worry! Create a new repo called USERNAME.github.com - it's really important that you use that name. Then, in the repo's admin page, scroll down & click on "Automatic Page Generator". Write over the default content, or do it later. Continue to layouts & choose a theme you like. Click publish, and in 10 minutes or so your site will be available. You can add pages to your repo and link to them, or put the content you want to share on your index.html. Hope that helps!

Comment: its username.github.com or if my name is pks then i have to use the repo name as pks.github.com

Comment: Replace "USERNAME" with your github user name.

Answer (score 4):

I had similar issues because my site was using HTTPS and Disqus was being served over HTTP.

I could `jekyll serve` and see the comments locally, but the comments did not show up on the live site. After a bit of searching and diffing I opened the Chrome Web Inspector and saw a series of errors like the two examples below:

> [blocked] The page at https://devblog.toopher.com/2013/07/05/enabling-travis-ci-for-fun-and-profit/ ran insecure content from http://toopherdevblog.disqus.com/embed.js.
>
> The page at https://devblog.toopher.com/2013/07/05/enabling-travis-ci-for-fun-and-profit/ displayed insecure content from https://i.stack.imgur.com/POLl6.png.

I edited the Disqus comment provider (`_includes/JB/comments-providers/disqus`) and changed the Disqus URL to `https://` like this:

```
dsq.src = 'https://' + disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/embed.js';
```

Hope that helps someone else!

Comment: You mean you edited the bit below "DON'T EDIT BELOW THIS LINE"

Answer (score 1):

First, let me tell you that I have worked with jekyll but I **do not** have **any** experience with jekyll bootstrap.

Second, after looking at your repo on github I think adding *{% include JB/comments-providers/disqus %}* to your post.html layout should solve the problem. This will load the javascript in your jekyll posts and thus enable comments, of course, after editing the _config.yml.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Make sure you have the url parameter in your `_config.yml` set correctly:

```
url: "https://GITHUBUSERNAME.github.io"
```

Also it goes without saying but wouldn't hurt to make sure to that your short name parameter is also correct:

```
disqus:
    shortname: your-short-name
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just need to create a site profile [here](https://disqus.com/admin/create/).

Hope this helps.